# How can I apply interpolation to angle data?

Tags: least-squares, curve-fitting, circular-statistics

My data is in angles (degrees) and I intend to write a code that is trying to understand if there is a systematic (biased) behaviour in data.

For example, if my data set is (10, 20, 30, 40) then a basic fit can find a relation like y=10*x. However, when it is like (340 350 0 10 20), even though same relation exits, my code cannot find it since there is no way for code to understand 350 to 0 is also a plus 10.

In other words, how can I write an interpolation code that works with modded numbers (in this case, mod360)?

(This is neccesary for a code that outs warnings when there is a systematic behaviour in data. After polynomial and exponential fits, goodness of fit tests are done and warnings are given for detected systematic behaviours. I need to make it work in angle data too, however modded number break the usual approach.)

Comment: Do you always want the smaller angle?  I.e., between 350 and 10 you want 00, not 180?

Comment: have you thought about converting to rectangular coordinates of the unit circle?  I.e. create new columns x=cos(theta) and y=sin(theta)?

Comment: It does not matter if numbers are small or big, It just needs to show if there is a systematic behaviour. I guess converting to rectangle would work, if both coordinates show bias, I could flag that case. I hope there is a cleaner solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem needs additional constraints in order to be identified. Let's look a the set you mention:
$$ x = (340, 350, 0, 10, 20),$$
and let's number the elements $n = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).$ Then, we can see that a perfect fit is $x = 330 + 10n.$ However, another perfect fit is $x = 330 + 370n.$ In fact, any fit $x = 330 + (360k + 10)n$ is a perfect fit for $k \in \mathbb{Z},$ that is, integer.

This problem is well known in circular regression, and one of the reasons why a linear model is rarely used. The linear model is sometimes called the "barber's pole" regression model.

If you want to use this model, a good approach is to look at the model as $x = \alpha + \beta n, $ and to constrain $-180 < \beta < 180.$ Then, we can optimize  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to obtain the best fit. Note that this optimization is not convex.